# Get value date on jsonobject data with format datetime yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS

Tags: android, json, date, datetime

i have some problem when i want to get data with tipe Date on JSONObject

i have Date like this :

```
    {
"error": false,
"alerts": {
    "code": "200",
    "message": "retrieve success"
},
"data": [{
    "incident__task_i_d": "8d37a3f1-d257-4833-9701-4eab0e48076f",
    "address": "Pulo Jahe Motor",
    "task_status": "Completed",
    "incident_i_d": "83eeed0f-4ea4-416b-8721-637e40ac9f72",
    "vehicle_i_d": "36420155-6214-4745-bbf3-7dae7d50ce9c",
    "agent_i_d": "1c3436fd-9338-4910-9686-8c1cd0a33433",
    "dispatched_time": "2016-08-12T08:29:47.89",
    "origin_latitude": "-6.8979664",
    "origin_longitude": "107.6135752",
    "destination_latitude": "-6.198816382772501",
    "destination_longitude": "106.921986633551",
    "created_dt": "2016-08-12T08:29:47.89",
    "departed_time": "2016-08-12T10:13:20.947",
    "arrival_time": "2016-08-12T10:11:14.93",
    "kick_off_time": "2016-08-12T10:13:54.54",
    "finished_time": "2016-08-12T10:14:30.893",
    "incident_reported_dt": "2016-08-11T08:21:34.23"
}]
    }
```

i have parse that date but doesn't work correctly . this my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS");
JsonElement dispatched_time = ((JsonObject)jaray.get(i)).get("dispatched_time");
modelRekap.setDispatched_time(sdf.parse(String.valueOf(dispatched_time.toString())));
```

and i have an error like this :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""2016-08-12T08:29:47.89"" (at offset 0)
```

can anyone help me ? Thank's

Comment: Not sure if it is the cause or not but since 'SS' is millisecond you better include 3 like 'SSS' instead of 2 'SS' so your Simple date format would look like: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

Comment: hmm when i change "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS doen't work >.<

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is based on the fact that 'SimpleDateFormat' has no idea what to do with "T" while formatting.

So your best option (as I know it) would be to do something like the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS");
JsonElement dispatched_time = ((JsonObject)jaray.get(i)).get("dispatched_time");
modelRekap.setDispatched_time(sdf.parse(dispatched_time.toString().replace("T", " ")));
```